# Text superimposed in a textbox

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have several textboxes that I want to put in my program. For each of those, I'd like to have text that explains what to input. I've seen them on more complex non-Python programs.

Instead of doing something like:

```
from Tkinter import *

top = Tk()
L1 = Label(top, text="User Name")
L1.pack( side = LEFT)
E1 = Entry(top, bd =5)

E1.pack(side = RIGHT)

top.mainloop()
```

I'd rather something like this: [Like This](http://img.viralpatel.net/2009/09/html-textbox-label-text.png)

Is there something even like this in tkinter? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
top = Tk()
E1 = Entry(top, bd =5)
E1.insert(0, "User Name")
E1.pack(side = RIGHT)
top.mainloop()
```

[see here for more info](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm).

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but it's perfect! Thanks!

Comment: You can probably improve this behavior a lot working with `on click` events, but unfortunately I am not so familiar with that to clarify it to you...